# Google Map Advanced Clustering

Tags: cluster-analysis, google-maps-markers, google-maps-api-2

www.fastfoodmaps.com

```
http://maps.forum.nu/server_side_clusterer/
```

im looking for multi color marker with clustering like sample the website above.

i found google api sample for single color marker with clustering concept.

Anyone have any sample or any website plz post here.

Answer (score 0):

I am using clusterer2: http://www.acme.com/javascript/#Clusterer when showing about 2000 shops in Google Maps.

You can see it in action at http://www.mrperswall.se/butiker by searching for "Stockholm" and then zoom out (customer specified that nothing should be shown until user has performed a search).

Comment: cool work but im looking for something like http://www.svennerberg.com/2009/01/handling-large-amounts-of-markers-in-google-maps/ & made it works :)